# generating tweet using R SOFTWARE

Tags: r

I am trying to write an r code that generate tweets in a particular location using the following code

```
token <- create_token(consumer_key = "1234", consumer_secret = "1234", access_token = "1234", access_secret = "1234")

states_a <- c("ondo", "ekiti", "ogun", "lagos", "osun", "oyo")
unemployment_tweets_a <- search_tweets(q = "#unemployment",location = states_a, n = 2000,
                                  lang = "en",
                                  include_rts = FALSE)
```

but the code keeps bringing out the code below

> Error in vapply(elements, encode, character(1)) :
> values must be length 1,
> but FUN(X[[5]]) result is length 6

I have trouble shoot but no headway

Comment: I think the issue may be `location = states_a`. It looks as though parameters to `search_tweets()` cannot be vectors with > 1 value. In addition, I don't think that `location` is a valid argument, either to the function or the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the location parameter in the search_tweets() function expects a single location, but the states_a variable passed to the function is a vector of multiple locations.

you can use lapply to achieve what you want:

```
library(rtweet)

auth <- rtweet_app()

# Create a function called FUN
FUN <- function(i) {
  search_tweets(q = "#unemployment",location = i, n = 2000,
                                       lang = "en",
                                       include_rts = FALSE, token = auth)
}


states_a <- c("ondo", "ekiti", "ogun", "lagos", "osun", "oyo")


# Use lapply to searh for each location
unemployment_tweets_a <- lapply(states_a, FUN)

# Then use rbind to convert the list to a dataframe
unemployment_tweets_a  <- do.call(rbind, unemployment_tweets_a)
```

In this way you will get tweets from all the 6 locations you have specified.

Comment: it brought out same error

Comment: Edited the response. worked for me just try to see if it works. But bear in mind you need to have Elevated access in order to run this otherwise it will produce an error.

Comment: i tried your code at asaei, I guess I have to have developer account on twitter. I have applied for it, hopefully it will be approved

Comment: i tried it on my old system it worked but on my new system it brought out invalid token. thank you so much